# Searching/predicting next terminal/non-terminal by CFG/Tree?

Tags: parsing, search, code-generation, prediction, context-free-grammar

I'm looking for algorithm to help me predict next token given a string/prefix and Context free grammar.

First question is what is the exact structure representing CFG. It seems it is a tree, but what type of tree ? I'm asking because the leaves are always ordered , is there a ordered-tree ?
May be if i know the correct structure I can find algorithm for bottom-up **search** !

If it is not exactly a **Search** problem, then the next closest thing it looks like **Parsing** the prefix-string and then **Generating** the next-token ? How do I do that ?

any ideas

---

my current generated grammar is simple it has no OR rules (except when i decide to reuse the grammar for new sequences, i will be). It is generated by Sequitur algo and is so called SLG(single line grammar) .. but if I generate it using many seq's the TOP rule will be Ex:>

```
S : S1 z S3 | u S2 .. S5 S1 | S4 S2 .. |... | Sn 
S1 : a b
S2 : h u y
...
```

..i.e. top-heavy SLG, except the top rule all others do not have OR |

---

As a side note I'm thinking of a ways to convert it to Prolog and/or DCG program, where may be there is easier way to do what I want easily ?! what do you think ?

Comment: How accurate a prediction do you need? And do you just want a single possible next token or do you want the complete set?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "what is the exact structure representing CFG". A CFG is an unordered set of productions, each of which maps a single non-terminal onto an ordered possibly empty sequence of grammar symbols. That's not very tree-like. The tree-like structure with ordered children shows up as the representation of a parse, for example.

Comment: i want may be several results ... 2-3

Comment: yeah.. the productions are unordered but the body of every production (if not | ) is ordered.. i fogot the OR case ..... because in my case so far they are always only AND, except the TOP production ..sorry

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: In abstract, this is a hard problem. But it can be pretty simple for given grammars. Everything depends on the nature of the grammar.

---

The basic algorithm indeed starts by using some parsing algorithm on the prefix. A rough prediction can then be made by attempting to continue the parse with each possible token, retaining only those which do not produce immediate errors.

That will certainly give you a list which includes all of the possible continuations. But the list may also include tokens which cannot appear in a correct input. Indeed, it is possible that the correct list is empty (because the given prefix is not the prefix of any correct input); this will happen if the parsing algorithm is unable to correctly verify whether a token sequence is a possible prefix.

In part, this will depend on the grammar itself. If the grammar is LR(1), for example, then the LR(1) parsing algorithm can precisely identify the continuation set. If the grammar is LR(k) for some k>1, then it is theoretically possible to produce an LR(1) grammar for the same language, but the resulting grammar might be impractically large. Otherwise, you might have to settle for "false positives". That might be acceptable if your goal is to provide tab-completion, but in other circumstances it might not be so useful.

The precise datastructure used to perform the internal parse and exploration of alternatives will depend on the parsing algorithm used. Many parsing algorithms, including the standard LR parsing algorithm whose internal data structure is a simple stack, feature a mutable internal state which is not really suitable for the exploration step; you could adapt such an algorithm by making a copy of the entire internal data structure (that is, the stack) before proceeding with each trial token. Alternatively, you could implement a copy-on-write stack. But the parser stack is not usually very big, so copying it each time is generally feasible. (That's what Bison does to produce expanded error messages with an "expected token" list, and it doesn't seem to trigger unacceptable runtime overhead in practice.)

Alternatively, you could use some variant of CYK chart parsing (or a GLR algorithm like the Earley algorithm), whose internal data structures can be implemented in a way which doesn't involve destructive modification. Such algorithms are generally used for grammars which are not LR(1), since they can cope with any CFG although highly ambiguous grammars can take a long time to parse (proportional to the cube of the input length). As mentioned above, though, you will get false positives from such algorithms.

If false positives are unacceptable, then you could use some kind of heuristic search to attempt to find an input sequence which completes the trial prefix. This can in theory take quite a long time, but for many grammars a breadth-first search can find a completion within a reasonable time, so you could terminate the search after a given maximum time. This will not produce false positives, but the time limit might prevent it from  finding the complete set of possible continuations.

Comment: my current generated grammar so far is simple it has no OR rules (except if i decide to reuse the grammar for new sequences). It is generated by Sequitur algo and is so called SLG(single line grammar) .. but if I generate it using many seq's the TOP rule will be >  S : S1 | S2 | S3 |... | Sn  ..i.e. top-heavy SLG

Comment: @sten: if your language is finite, the solution is much simpler. But that's covered by my summary statement: everything depends on the particular nature of the grammar. If you can write a more specific question, you could get a more specific answer. (But please ask a new question rather than edit this one.)

Comment: just tested it ;) converting CFG to DCG and then Prolog does rest i.e. parsing&prediction ... now just have to figure how to implement/convert CFG to pure Prolog with difference-lists instead of DCG, because python based Prolog's dont support DCG ! :) thanks ..